# Flask route to method with add_url_rule

Tags: python, flask, python-3.7

I'm trying to write a server with Flask.

I'd like to route to class's method with a name other than the HTTP method name, however an error occurs if the source code below.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
pkg_prefix = "application.route."

app.add_url_rule('/test', view_func=import_module(pkg_prefix + 'test').Test.as_view('post_test_user'), methods=['POST'])
```

AssertionError: Unimplemented method 'POST'

```
class Test:

    def post_test_user(self):
        ・・・
        return self.respons
```

How do I route request to this "post_test_user" method without changing method name?

A lot of thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this code

```
app.add_url_rule('/test', view_func=import_module(pkg_prefix + 'test').Test().post_test_user, methods=['POST'])
```

Comment: I would be weary of this approach, as Test() is instantiating an instance of class "Test" , and may have undesirable consequences if an __init__() method or other initialization code is later added to the class.